# ECC - Unable to produce entire cyclic group

Tags: python, math, cryptography, curves

I am reading the section about elliptic curve cryptography in Christoffer Paares book ("Understanding Cryptography"). I decided that I would implement a function for elliptic curve point addition and point doubling in python. For my test I used the example in the book so I could test my results.

The curve used in the example is: y^2 = x^3 + 2x + 2 mod 17

The generator used is: p = (5,1)

Thus the cycle becomes:

1p  = (5,1)

2p  = (6,3)

3p  = (10,6)

4p  = (3,1)

5p  = (9,16)

6p  = (16,13)

7p  = (0,6)

8p  = (13,7)

9p  = (7,6)

10p = (7,1)

11p = (13,10)

12p = (0,11)

13p = (16,4)

14p = (9,1)

15p = (3,16)

16p = (10,11)

17p = (6,14)

18p = (5,16)

19p = The neutral element (Point at infinity)

20p = (5,1)

...

I wrote this code in an attempt to reproduce the results:

```
def add(a,p,P,Q):
   #Check For Neutral Element
   if P == (0,0) or Q == (0,0):
       return (P[0]+Q[0],P[1]+Q[1])

   #Check For Inverses (Return Neutral Element - Point At Infinity)
   if P[0] == Q[0]:
       if (-P[1])%p == Q[1] or (-Q[1])%p == P[1]:
           return (0,0)

   #Calculate Slope
   if P != Q:
       s = (Q[1]-P[1]) / (Q[0]-P[0])
   else:
       s = ((3*(P[0]*P[0])+a)%p) ** (2*P[1])

   #Calculate Third Intersection
   x = s*s - P[0] - Q[0]
   y = (s*(P[0]-x)) - P[1]

   y = y%p
   x = x%p

   return (x,y)

r = (5,1)
for i in range(1,20):
   print i,':',r
   r = add(2,17,r,(5,1))
```

However the output is:

1. : (5, 1)
2. : (6, 3)
3. : (10, 6)
4. : (3, 1)
5. : (9, 16)
6. : (12, 9)
7. : (1, 2)
8. : (12, 9)
9. : (1, 2)
10. : (12, 9)
11. : (1, 2)
12. : (12, 9)
13. : (1, 2)
14. : (12, 9)
15. : (1, 2)
16. : (12, 9)
17. : (1, 2)
18. : (12, 9)
19. : (1, 2)

As you might see it follows the expected result until 6p and then enters a cycle with the length of 2. I have been staring at this for hours now and I still don't know why it doesn't work (after all: how hard can it be... it's 30 lines of python) .

Comment: There are never any floating points or rounding in your implementation, the division is truncated (in Python 2). Is this intended, as the algorithm dictates it or could it be where the error lies?

Comment: Floating point operations shouldn't be needed. Generally you never use floating points in crypto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really aware of the topic but here is a link to a repository implementing the ECC: [github](https://github.com/amintos/PyECC/blob/master/ecc/elliptic.py#L90)

**Edit:** The actual problem is the division modulo p. You can't just divide using integer arithmetics (15 / 4 == 3) but need to multiply by the **inverse** of 4 modulo 17 instead.
The inverse of 4 modulo 17 is 13, because 4 * 13 % 17 == 1. Your fraction becomes 15*13, which is the equivalent of saying »15 * 1/4 modulo 17«. Just put some debug prints around your slope computation and you will see when the inversion begins to differ from simple integer division.

```
def euclid(a, b):
    '''Solve x*a + y*b = ggt(a, b) and return (x, y, ggt(a, b))'''
    # Non-recursive approach hence suitable for large numbers
    x = yy = 0
    y = xx = 1
    while b:
        q = a // b
        a, b = b, a % b
        x, xx = xx - q * x, x
        y, yy = yy - q * y, y
    return xx, yy, a

def inv(a, n):
    '''Perform inversion 1/a modulo n. a and n should be COPRIME.'''
    # coprimality is not checked here in favour of performance
    i = euclid(a, n)[0]
    while i < 0:
        i += n
    return i

def add(a,p,P,Q):
   #Check For Neutral Element
   if P == (0,0) or Q == (0,0):
       return (P[0]+Q[0],P[1]+Q[1])

   #Check For Inverses (Return Neutral Element - Point At Infinity)
   if P[0] == Q[0]:
       if (-P[1])%p == Q[1] or (-Q[1])%p == P[1]:
           return (0,0)

   #Calculate Slope 
   if P != Q:

       # perform multiplication with the inverse modulo p
       s = (Q[1]-P[1]) * inv(Q[0]-P[0], p)
   else:
       s = ((3*(P[0]*P[0])+a)%p) ** (2*P[1])

   #Calculate Third Intersection
   x = s*s - P[0] - Q[0]
   y = (s*(P[0]-x)) - P[1]

   y = y%p
   x = x%p

   return (x,y)

r = (5,1)
for i in range(1,20):
   print i,':',r
   r = add(2,17,r,(5,1))
```

prints

```
1 : (5, 1)
2 : (6, 3)
3 : (10, 6)
4 : (3, 1)
5 : (9, 16)
6 : (16, 13)
7 : (0, 6)
8 : (13, 7)
9 : (7, 6)
10 : (7, 11)
11 : (13, 10)
12 : (0, 11)
13 : (16, 4)
14 : (9, 1)
15 : (3, 16)
16 : (10, 11)
17 : (6, 14)
18 : (5, 16)
19 : (0, 0)
```

Here a link to [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ecc/0.0.1).
Feel free to use or improve it.